# Get directory entries for "slow protocols" asynchronously

Tags: linux, go, exec, ls, gvfs

I want a function for getting directory entries on Linux. I use [`ioutil.ReadDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadDir) and usually it is fast.
But if I want to read some mounted virtual file system on `/run/user/1000/gvfs/`, this function becomes slow. If the directory has many file entries I need to wait a long time.

I can use the `ls` command in a terminal and result will be the same.
When I tried `ls -U -a -p -1` I got line by line output immediately.
I tried running this in Go with `exec.Command`, but it didn't work asynchronously. Go is waiting for full program output. What did I do wrong?

```golang
m.cmd = exec.Command("ls", "-U", "-a", "-p", "-1")
// for example some "slow" directory:
m.cmd.Dir = "/run/user/1000/gvfs/dav:host=webdav.yandex.ru,ssl=true,user=...../" 
reader, _ := m.cmd.StdoutPipe()
bufReader := bufio.NewReader(reader)
go func() {
  m.cmd.Start()
  for {
    line, _, err := bufReader.ReadLine()
    if err != nil {
      break
    }
    linestr := string(line)
    if linestr != "./" && linestr != "../" {
      fmt.Println(linestr)
    }
  }
}()
```

I need line by line printing immediately in Go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `ls -U -a -p 1 | cat` to see if you get line-by-line output.

Go doesn't control `ls`; `ls` does line-by-line writing if *`ls`* chooses to do so, and `ls` chooses *not* to do that when its output is a pipe.  You could allocate a pty pair and use that, but that's the wrong way to do this.

`ioutil.ReadDir` first reads the entire directory (by calling `Readdir(-1)`), then sorts the file names.  If you use `os.Open` to open the directory, then call the [`Readdir`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdir) or [`Readdirnames`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames) function with a small (but not negative) number, you should get something more to your liking.

Comment: this solved my problem:

f, err0 := os.Open(path)
if err0 == nil {
 for {
  files, err1 := f.Readdir(10) /* any number >=1*/
  if err1 == nil {
   if files[j].IsDir() {
    Prln(files[j].Name()+"/")
   } else {
    Prln(files[j].Name())
   }
  } else {
   break
  }
 }
 f.Close()
}